# 'though however' used together

Tags: word-usage

I have come across a video in which the speaker says something like

*What the Commons is, though however, is ...*

Why use 'though however' together? Is the sentence with double '*is* correct?

You can hear the whole utterance here:

http://news.bbc.co.uk/2/hi/uk_news/politics/8101854.stm

Comment: The double 'is' causes me no problems, though some might object purely on style grounds. The 'though however' is redundancy; I'd drop the 'though'.

Comment: How many times does one repeat a word while speaking? I guess the answer is many. Sometimes they say something then drop it in favor of a better or different word. And I think this is one of those instances.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth Yes 'though' and 'however' are really serving the same purpose, and only one of them is needed - preferably 'however'. If this is an extract from speech, it is unsurprising. None of us ever speak in a manner which would pass muster if it was committed directly to paper. We frequently repeat words, duplicate expressions, stop before the end of a sentence and say things like 'You know what I mean?'. Conversation is an altogether different skill to writing and you can't simply convert one to the other without some editing.

Comment: People use various devices, while speaking, to gain time for their brains to catch up with their mouths. One is to say many things (keeping the mouth busy) with only one meaning (so the brain can work on something else). Another is "umm ... well ...". Another is to just shut up for a moment, but that tends to invite interruptions.

Answer (score 1):

Both instances of *is* are syntactically necessary. It would be ungrammatical to omit one of them and say ‘what the commons is . . .  the representatives from every constituency’.

It might be different in a piece of edited prose, but in the context of a speech, *however* reinforces the contrast marked by *though*.

Comment: I like the idea of reinforcement :) Do you often hear 'however' used this way?

Comment: No, but I can't say I've been listening for it.